# Force recompile of filtered ng-attr without $scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am programming a chat application in which I want to have human-readable relative timestamps on messages. I am using a filter that takes in the JS timestamp and (with the Moment.js library) outputs a string representing the relative time (such as "a few seconds ago"). Here are relevant code excerpts:

HTML:

```
<li ng-attr-title="{{timestamp | moment}}"></li>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("ChatApp").
filter("moment",function(){
    return function(jstimestamp){
        //using the Moment.js library to create a relative-time string
        return moment(parseInt(jstimestamp)).fromNow();
    }
});
```

How do I force AngularJS to recalculate `ng-attr-title` periodically even when `$scope.timestamp` never changes, so that "a few seconds ago" will be updated to "a minute ago" and so on? Currently it only updates when the page is reloaded.

Comment: did you try [this directive](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)?

Comment: @Manasov Daniel I believe it doesn't solve the problem, as cchan3141 is already using the moment library. Do you know that it has a mechanism for self updating the bindings ?

Comment: @Boris that directive just uses Timeout based on how old is message

Comment: @ManasovDaniel I just double checked, the [am-time-ago directive](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#am-time-ago-directive) indeed uses timeout to update the state. I still believe it's a bad idea, and would opt for changing the time on refresh only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to make your filter stateful so it is evaluated on every digest even if the input value does not change.

```js
angular.module("ChatApp").
filter("moment", function() {

  function innerFilter(jstimestamp) {
    //using the Moment.js library to create a relative-time string
    return moment(parseInt(jstimestamp)).fromNow();
  }
  innerFilter.$stateful = true;

  return innerFilter;
});
```

You can add an interval in your controller to make it work without user input.

```
var intervalPromise = $interval(function() {}, 1000);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
});
```

There no need to call apply inside the interval since each tick of $interval will trigger a digest cycle already.

You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p9uAiC1vpSGErhDfBiss?p=preview).

You can find more information on stateful filters in the documentation page [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Comment: This is actually really cool whoa - but it doesn't update until I interact with the page and trigger a $digest. I think I'll combine this with the other answer and see what happens.

Comment: I added the info from @Boris 's answer, and made a working plnkr example.

Comment: @cchan3141 I updated the example so it cleans up the interval when the current scope is destroyed.

Comment: [except that $scope.on should be $scope.$on]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bad idea, but it could work by manually triggering an `$apply` cycle. Be wary of the performance impact, as it will run on all of your bindings. This will refresh your bindings each second, you can adjust it to your desire:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.run(['$interval', '$rootScope', function ($interval, $rootScope) {
      $interval(function () {
        $rootScope.$apply();
      }, 1000, 0, false);
    }]);
```

Comment: @cchan3141 no it wouldn't as it's a method on the [Scope object](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), i.e. `$rootScope` or `$scope` if not named differently.

Comment: Hm ok. Also, I tried `setInterval($rootScope.$apply,1000)` and it keeps saying `this.$eval is not a function at r.$apply` - I suppose that's why the $interval wrapper exists

Comment: The `$interval` wrapper makes angular aware of the changes while `setInterval` is outside of angular scope. Your call fails because it's being called in local scope, and messes up the `this` binding within `$apply`. That's why I called inside `$interval` callback `function () {$rootScope.$apply();}`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Darn, I still have a lot to learn about Angular's workings :D